# How to add a column in specific row using a view in sqlite?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, view

I have 3 tables in a database in sqlite

> **Table A**

```
+-----+-------+
|  id | name  |
+-----+-------+
| 1   | Ann   |
| 2   | Bill  |
| 3   | Mike  |
| 4   | Zoey  |
+-----+-------+
```

> **Table B**

```
+-----+-----+
| idA | idC |
+-----+-----+
| 1   | 1   |
| 1   | 2   |
| 2   | 3   |
| 3   | 2   |
| 4   | 1   |
+-----+-----+
```

> **Table C**

```
+-----+-----+
|  id | type|
+-----+-----+
| 1   | x   |
| 2   | y   |
| 3   | z   |
+-----+-----+
```

I have tried:

```
CREATE VIEW test AS SELECT A.id, A.name, C.type
FROM A, B, C
WHERE B.idA = A.id
AND B.idB = B.id
```

Then i get:

```
**View test**
+-----+-------+-------+
|  id | name  | type  |
+-----+-------+-------+
| 1   | Ann   | x     |
| 1   | Ann   | y     |
| 2   | Bill  | z     |
| 3   | Mike  | y     |
| 4   | Zoey  | x     |
+-----+-------+-------+
```

But i'm want to do something like this

```
+-----+-------+-------+
|  id | name  | type  |
+-----+-------+-------+
| 1   | Ann   | x,y   |
| 2   | Bill  | z     |
| 3   | Mike  | y     |
| 4   | Zoey  | x     |
+-----+-------+-------+
```

Without repeat any row, is this posible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite supports `GROUP_CONCAT()`

```
CREATE VIEW test 
AS
SELECT  A.id, A.name, GROUP_CONCAT(C.type) AS Type
FROM    A, B, C
WHERE   B.idA = A.id AND 
        B.idC = C.id
GROUP   BY A.id, A.name
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!7/251ec/5)

OUTPUT

```
╔════╦══════╦══════╗
║ id ║ name ║ Type ║
╠════╬══════╬══════╣
║  1 ║ Ann  ║ x,y  ║
║  2 ║ Bill ║ z    ║
║  3 ║ Mike ║ y    ║
║  4 ║ Zoey ║ x    ║
╚════╩══════╩══════╝
```

From SQLite Documentation

> The `group_concat()` function returns a string which is the
>   concatenation of all non-NULL values of X. If parameter Y is present
>   then it is used as the separator between instances of X. A comma (",")
>   is used as the separator if Y is omitted. The order of the
>   concatenated elements is arbitrary.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for the query when defining your view:

```
SELECT A.id, A.name, GROUP_CONCAT(C.type) type
FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON B.idA = A.id
INNER JOIN C ON C.id = B.idC
GROUP BY A.id
```

Check out the MySQL documentation for [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)